# Degree of a root term?

Tags: exponentiation

I had the textbook question:

> What is the degree of the following expression:
>
> $x^2\sqrt{y-5}$

Would it be 2.5, since it would be the sum of the exponents of $x$ (2) and $y$ (.5, I think)? Or is this wrong?

The confusing part is the exponent of $y$, because it is not $\sqrt{y}$, but $\sqrt{y-5}$. Would $y$'s exponent still be $y^{1/2}$?

Comment: but this is not a polynomial

Comment: You are dealing with  homogeneous functions?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Sorry, the question included other polynomials, and you would find the degree of this the same way as the largest degree of a polynomial

Comment: @Albert Sorry, what is a homogenous function? This is simply a monomial, a single-termed expression.

Comment: A function $f(x,y)$ is said to be homogeneous with degree $n$ if $f(\lambda x,\lambda y)=\lambda^{n}f(x,y)$.

Comment: In the case $\sqrt{y}$ the expression is homogeneous with degree $2.5$ and in the case $\sqrt{y-5}$ the expression is not homogeneous.